# Logstash config with filebeat issue when using both beats and file input

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am trying to config a filebeat with logstash. At the moment I managed to successfully config filebeat with logstash and I am running into same issues when creating multiple conf files in the logstash.
So currently I have one filebeats input which is something like :

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
  if [@metadata][pipeline] {
        elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        manage_template => false
        index => "systemsyslogs"
        pipeline => "%{[@metadata][pipeline]}"
        }}
else {
        elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        manage_template => false
        index => "systemsyslogs"
        }

}}
```

And a file Logstash config which is like :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/foldername/number.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
 }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{WORD:username} %{INT:number} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}" }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "numberlogtest"
  }
}
```

The grok filter is working as I successfully managed to create 2 index patterns in kibana and view the data correctly.
The problem is that when I am running logstash with both configs applied, logstash is fetching the data from  number.log multiple times and logstash plain logs are getting lots of warning, therefore using a lot of computing resources and CPU is going over 80% ( this is an oracle instance ). If I remove the file config from logstash the system is running properly.
I managed to run logstash with each one of these config files applied individually, but not both at once.

I already added an exception in the filebeats config :

```
 exclude_files:
  - /var/log/foldername/*.log
```

Logstash plain logs when running both config files:

```
[2023-02-15T12:42:41,077][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][39aca10fa204f31879ff2b20d5b917784a083f91c2eda205baefa6e05c748820] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"numberlogtest", :routing=>nil}, {"service"=>{"type"=>"system"}
"caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:607"}}}}}
```

I already added an exception in the filebeat config :

```
 exclude_files:
  - /var/log/foldername/*.log
```

Comment: How are you running Logstash with the two configs?

Comment: Also you can send the events from filebeat directly to ES and let logstash run only with file input.

Comment: So you are telling me in , for e..g. on my ubuntu  directory /etc/logstash/conf.d , I am supposed to have only one .conf file with the input, output configuration? And the solution would be to send logs from filebeats directly to ES without being processed by logstash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by creating a single logstash config with both inputs :

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
  file {
    path => "**path**"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  if [path] == "**path**" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{WORD:username} %{INT:number} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}" }
    }
  }
}

output {
  if [@metadata][pipeline] {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      manage_template => false
      index => "index1"
      pipeline => "%{[@metadata][pipeline]}"
    }
  } else {
    if [path] == "**path**" {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        manage_template => false
        index => "index2"
      }
    } else {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        manage_template => false
        index => "index1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```